# issues with mysql connection in java: No suitable Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm making a small program in Java that uses a Mysql connection but im getting some problems with the jdbc drivers. I installed Java EE and Java SE but i still get the message that there are no suitable driver for `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test`. Can someone explain to me what i am doing wrong.

Code:

```
public class Mysql_Connection_2 {


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static String query = "select count(*) from stock";    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {           
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MysqlConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }          
        MysqlConnection.dbConnection(query);
    }  
}
```

Extern Connection class:

```
public class MysqlConnection {

    private static final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test";
    private static final String dbuname = "root";
    private static final String dbpass = "usbw";

    static Connection dbcon = null;
    static Statement stmt = null;
    static ResultSet rs = null;



    public static void dbConnection (String query){

        try{         
            //getting database connection to MySQL server
            dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbuname, dbpass);

            //getting PreparedStatment to execute query
            stmt = dbcon.prepareStatement(query);

            //Resultset returned by query
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()) {
                int count = rs.getInt(1);
                System.out.println("count of stock : " + count);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage());           
        }       
    }   

}
```

Comment: have you added oracle driver jar file

Comment: Can you please explain the significance of having Oracle connection and MySQL connection in your question?

Comment: Is the jar on your classpath?

Comment: Also in class MysqlConnection you are trying to access `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();` > Strange ???

Comment: @hd1 Yes the jar is on my classpath

Comment: And you need to load the right driver, you're loading the oracle driver and you should be loading the mysql driver

Comment: The default port of mysql is 3306,have changed it while installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As pointed out in above answers, for MySql you should use

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

2) Make sure you have jar in classpath.
You can download jar from mvnrepo [MVNREPO](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.21)

3) Port is 3306 for MySql?

And a quick google for JAVA + MYSQL gives me [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/)

Comment: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` hasn't been necessary since Java 6 / JDBC 4.0 as long as you use a JDBC 4.0 driver.

Answer (score 2):

1. First You need to correct your driver

   `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`
2. Then Check You added mysql connector jar file
3. after that you need to make sure that jar file is added to your class path or not.

Correct the First one and go to second and then third

Comment: I think the order should be 2,3 then 1. The first step for anyone would do is to make sure they have the jar. Then they will add to the class path before going hard on keyboard.

Comment: Actually 1 is the basic Error. You have to correct it first right. Then still database is not connecting then go to 2 and 3 thats what i thought.

Comment: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` hasn't been necessary since Java 6 / JDBC 4.0 as long as you use a JDBC 4.0 driver.

Answer (score 1):

I can see one problem here. You are using Oracle driver to perform operation on the MySQL database.

```
try {           
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
}
```

Try this.

You need not specify the port number if you are using the default port.`jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName` should do

Comment: What should i use then?

Comment: I tried this but im getting a ClassNotFound exception

Comment: @Dibya, you have passed the url of database and not driver class.

Comment: @The_MonsterL: Are you using an IDE? If yes then make sure you have the correct drivers added to the class path.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar: Miskate while rearranging the answer.. ;) fixed it. Thanks for notifing..

Comment: @Dibya Happens all the time :) with all of us.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use mysql then the class should be `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` and you should have mysql jdbc connectivity jar file in class path.

Initialize the driver using

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access mysql database through oracle driver so you are getting error

try to use

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
try {           
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
}
```

and

```
private static final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
```

Comment: A constant variable name is in all caps. Try using DB_URL.. :)